# C# trouble passing inline code

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, inline-code

Hey I know there are a lot of questions already that contain the answer I need, but I'm having a hard time sifting between Func/Action/Delegate/Lambda, and as a javascript guy it all feels needlessly complex.

I'm working with 2d arrays and would like to write a method that accepts int width, int height, and any form of inline code to be called with every x/y pair. The point is just to avoid the bugs and time from writing a nested for loop over and over. But I'm unsure about the proper type of inline code to use, or what that looks like. I've tried a bunch of combos but can't make it work out.

What signature should I use on the method, and how do I call that?

Comment: Please show us the definition of your 2D array.

Comment: Yes. I was using x and y to mean the iterating variable in the for loops. Where ultimately the point is to call " thePassedInlineCode(x,y) "

Comment: I have different representations of 2d data. This is the main reason I would like a method to simplely generate every integer coordinate and pass them to specific code

Comment: My real issue is picking the right kind of inline code, and using that in a method signature, and then calling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use action as the type parameter, and a lambda when calling:

```
ForEachPair(5, 5, (x, y) =>
{
    Console.Write(x + "," + y);
});

public void ForEachPair(int width, int height, Action<int, int> callback)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            callback(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways to do this, one of the simplest and best ways is to define a delegate and accept that as an argument.

```
delegate void XYFunction(int x, int y); // define the return type and args

void ForEachXYPair(int width, int height, XYFunction func)
{
    // open your loop however
    {
        func(x, y);
    }
}
```

And then to call it...

```
ForEachXYPair(4, 4, (int x, int y) => { work; });
// OR
ForEachXYPair(4, 4, new XYFunction(AMethodForAbstractionsSake));
```